# Parcel JS: tree.render is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, npm, svg, parceljs

Whenever I try to run production build command `npm run build` or `npx parcel build index.html`, I get this error. I have a simple html and css project, no react, no 3rd party library Why could this be happening? I have tried parcel versions 1.12.3, 1.12.4 and 1.12.5.

Here is the error:

```
/Users/user/Documents/HTML Apps/Project/index.html: tree.render is not a function
at /Users/user/Documents/HTML Apps/Project/node_modules/htmlnano/lib/modules/minifySvg.js:19:23
at /Users/user/Documents/HTML Apps/Project/node_modules/posthtml/lib/api.js:91:45
at traverse (/Users/user/Documents/HTML Apps/Project/node_modules/posthtml/lib/api.js:105:26)
at traverse (/Users/user/Documents/HTML Apps/Project/node_modules/posthtml/lib/api.js:111:5)
at traverse (/Users/user/Documents/HTML Apps/Project/node_modules/posthtml/lib/api.js:105:17)
at traverse (/Users/user/Documents/HTML Apps/Project/node_modules/posthtml/lib/api.js:111:5)
at traverse (/Users/user/user/HTML Apps/Project/node_modules/posthtml/lib/api.js:105:17)
at traverse (/Users/user/Documents/HTML Apps/Project/node_modules/posthtml/lib/api.js:111:5)
at traverse (/Users/user/Documents/HTML Apps/Project/node_modules/posthtml/lib/api.js:105:17)
at traverse (/Users/user/Documents/HTML Apps/Project/node_modules/posthtml/lib/api.js:111:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Project@1.0.0 build: `parcel build index.html`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Project@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2021-04-14T07_44_52_872Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In my case it worked adding .htmlnanorc.js to my project root with the following:

```
module.exports = {
    "minifySvg": false
  }
```

Answer (score 26):

Turns out you can get around this by configuring `htmlnano` to *not* minify SVG.

Add a `.htmlnanorc` file to your project root, with a JSON configuration object like this:

```
{
    "minifySvg": false
}
```

The relevant part of the documentation is [here for V1](https://parceljs.org/html.html#htmlnano) (which actually doesn't mention the minifySvg setting) or [here for V2](https://v2.parceljs.org/languages/html/#htmlnano).

Answer (score 6):

`parcel build --no-optimize index.html` 
It will jump the optimization of parcel and let you going on.
Hope it’s helpful.
very easy way pls upvote

Comment: "--no-minify: This option has been renamed to --no-optimize." https://parceljs.org/getting-started/migration/#--no-minify

Comment: --no-optimize updated.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it worked by using an IMG tag with the SVG as the src.

You can weigh the pro's & con's yourself:
[Adding vector graphics to the Web | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Adding_vector_graphics_to_the_Web)

Note: I'm not sure if doing it this way is less efficient/optimized or not.

If someone sees anything wrong with this approach please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me.

just

```
parcel build index.html --no-minify
```

i think is deprecated because of --no-optmize